# Combining Restrictions and Projections on DetachedCriteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria, detachedcriteria

I have  problem with combining Restrictions and  Projections on DetachedCriteria.
If I use only Restriction or Projections separately the program works.
How can I combine those two together?

I have following sql:

```
 select cTopic.topic ,SUM(cTopic.records) as records 
 from Topics cTopic 
 where cTopic.id=? and cTopic.active =? 
 GROUP BY cTopic.topic 
 order by cTopic.orderTopics
```

The following Java codes work fine without using group by (setProjection)

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Coursetopics.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("active","Y"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id.courseid",Id)));

List<Coursetopics> sumList =  (List<Coursetopics>) hibernateTemplate
                                      .findByCriteria(criteria);
```

if I add following line of code before last line(List) the program does not work properly.

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add( Projections.sum("records"))
                        .add( Projections.groupProperty("topic") ));
```

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: No I did not get any exception

Comment: SO what do you mean by not working?

Comment: without projections the stdout: DEBUG org.hibernate.pretty.Printer  - Coursetopics{topic=Efficiency, id=component[id,courseid,section]{id=143, courseid=191, section=goals}, active=Y, orderTopics=13, records=5}    - with 16 rows data

Comment: with projections: DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL  - select sum(this_.records) as y0_, this_.topic as y1_ from coursetopics this_ where this_.active=? and this_.courseid=? group by this_.topic
Hibernate: select sum(this_.records) as y0_, this_.topic as y1_ from coursetopics this_ where this_.active=? and this_.courseid=? group by this_.topic
17657 [http-8095-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher  - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
17657 [http-8095-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader  - result row: 
17657 [http-8095-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader  - result row:

Comment: why are you using id.courseid in the Restriction. Can you add the class definition to the question as well. Also try the Projection.sum("this.id") instead of "records"